# ¿Cómo Enviar Datos De Java a un Servidor Web?

Tags: java, http

Ya tengo el servidor y las URL que se encargan de atender las peticiones del cliente, pero por ahora sólo funcionan en un navegador web, por ejemplo si quiero insertar datos, en el navegador pondría algo cómo:

```
http://localhost:8080/MiProyecto/insertar?nombre=Luis&Apellido=Juarez
```

Y el servidor se encarga de procesar los datos una vez que los recibe, pero en Java cómo podría mandar datos a través de una URL cómo el ejemplo anterior.

Comment: Tienes que abrir un URL. Mira este post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977221/open-url-in-java-to-get-the-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977221/open-url-in-java-to-get-the-content)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Java, es posible *invocar* una URL ([`java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)) a través de [`java.net.URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) sin requerir de librerías externas.

📖 De acuerdo con Harold (2013), el siguiente es el mínimo número de pasos para recuperar datos de un objecto `URLConnection`:

1. Construir un objecto `URL`.
2. Invocar el método `openConnection()` para recuperar un objecto `URLConnection` para esa URL.
3. Invocar el método `getInputStream()` de `URLConnection`.
4. Leer el flujo de bytes con la API usual.

💻 Esto es (con la URL que has proporcionado):

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/MiProyecto/insertar?nombre=Luis&Apellido=Juarez";

try {
    URLConnection conn = new URL(url).openConnection();
    try (InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(stream, "UTF-8")) {
        sc.useDelimiter("\\A");
        if (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.printf("Respuesta: %s", sc.next());
        }
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "URL error", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Logger.getAnonymousLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "IO error", e);
}
```

---

📓 *Referencias*

Harold, E. (2013). *Java network programming*. Sebastopol, CA: O'Reilly.